# how to add main to send parameter to calculate (python postfix calculator)

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, calculator

I defined a stack class and i have postfixEval method which is taking a string. 
These code I have work fine, but how can I make it to work with argument on the command line?
Sample execution: python myCode.py 3 5 + 2 *

```
class Stack:
     def __init__(self):
         self.items = []

     def isEmpty(self):
         return self.items == []

     def push(self, item):
         self.items.append(item)

     def pop(self):
         return self.items.pop()

     def peek(self):
         return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

     def size(self):
         return len(self.items)

def postfixEval(postfixExpr):
    operandStack = Stack()
    tokenList = postfixExpr.split()

    for token in tokenList:
        if token in "+-/*^":
            operand2 = operandStack.pop()
            operand1 = operandStack.pop()
            result = doMath(token,operand1,operand2)
            operandStack.push(result)
        else:
            operandStack.push(int(token))
    return operandStack.pop()

def doMath(op, op1, op2):
    if op == "*":
        return op1 * op2
    elif op == "/":
        return op1 / op2
    elif op == "+":
        return op1 + op2
    else:
        return op1 - op2

print(postfixEval('7 8 + 3 2 + /'))
```

Comment: It's not safe to read the expression as a "naked" string of command line arguments, since the shell may do funny things with your operators, especially `*`. You should read the expression as a `'quoted string'`, which you can get from the `sys.argv` list.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, if you sure that your shell not reinterpret your expression in some wrong way:

```
print(postfixEval(" ".join(sys.argv[1:])))
```

or you can pass your expression as one string: `myCode.py '2+2'`
then as expression in your program you can use just `sys.argv[1]`